# How do I type CTRL + ] on a QWERTZ keyboard (in order to jump to a tag with Vim)?

Tags: vim

In Vim, the usual way to jump to the definition of the keyword under the cursor is to type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> (as claimed by [`:he CTRL-\]`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tagsrch.html#CTRL-])).

But when you have a QWERTZ keyboard (see below, <kbd>Strg</kbd> is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>), you're in some trouble: there is no separate <kbd>]</kbd> key on the keyboard; you'll have to press <kbd>ALT GR</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> to type the `]`. So, to jump to a tag, it`s neccessary to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT GR</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> which doesn't work (and is also not feasible because you'll break your fingers if you happen to use that often).

[image: QUERTZ keyboard]

So, how could I jump to a tag using my QWERTZ keyboard?

In addition, I'd also be glad if someone could explain why pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT GR</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> does **not** work.

---

**Edit:**
I'm not interested in the obvious answers "remap to something else" or "press the mouse button".

---

Duplicate on Vi/Vim: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5732/tag-navigation-using-ctrl-does-not-work-with-non-english-keyboard-on-windows

Comment: You can try remapping the command to a different key combination

Comment: @Benjamin: that's the obvious answer I'm **not** looking for. I refuse to believe that it's simply not possible without remapping (and using the mouse which is currently my fallback solution). Forgot to mention that in the question. Updated now. Thank you.

Comment: I guess the answer is no, there is no out-of-the-box key combination that would work for you. It sucks (I know, I have a non-US keyboard as well) but it's mostly because there are so many different keyboard layouts you can only use a-z (if even them) and 0-9 if you want to be sure the keyword combo works for everyone.

Comment: Huh? _I'm not interested in the obvious answers "remap to something else"_ So, if there were a (say) ctrl-a to do the same, what's the difference to a simple map? But if you **really** don't want it, then it's simple! buy a US keyboard. I also don't live in the US but I own a US keyboard. And if you don't want to do that, patch Vim and build your own version. It's not that difficult. Alternatively, if none of these work, use Emacs. And if it doesn't work for you, go ahead and start using Notepad++. Or TextMate, if you're in a Mac. It rocks.

Comment: @sidyll: I simply want to know if there's a way to jump to a tag using a QWERTZ keyboard. Of course I could remap, but lots of Vim's features have different ways to access them. I guessed there was another -- built in -- way to jump to a tag.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd not be willing to remap keys. Its for situations just like this that vim has remapping... and its so trivial to do ... so I'm going to risk your wrath (but help anyone else stuck with this issue)- to remap do a `:nmap #t <C-]>` and `#t` is now `C-]` (replace # with whichever key you don't use often..). Add it to your .vimrc and you'll be forever happy.

Comment: @Michael Anderson: yes, I could. But as the accepted answer shows, it's not neccessary. Remapping would of course work. But when I switch computers, I have to keep my `.vimrc` consistent or I'll use the mapping. I versioned my `$HOME` as git repo and use it on various boxes. Yes. But why should I take the effort if it's not neccessary (like the answer shows)?

Comment: @Juhana: see the answer. The answer is **not** no :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As weird as it reads, on AZERTY keyboards (french layout specifically) `$` is at the same spot as `]` on QWERTY keyboards so I must hit `<C-$>` to jump to definition.

See if `<C-+>` does the trick.

Comment: **This** is the answer I was looking for. Pressing `CTRL-+` on the QWERTZ keyboard jumps to a tag! Thank you!

Comment: I struggled a bit on this particular thing until I found the answer on a totally unrelated thread on a french linux forum. I'm glad it helped you.

Comment: On my AZERTY keyboard, I need to press `CTRL-ALT GR-$` or `CTRL-ALT GR-]` to jump to the identifier under the cursor. I now the OP specifically asked not to remap, I'll still mention that I remapped it to `CTRL M` in my `~/.vimrc` `noremap <C-m> <C-]>`. More details in [an answer to a question specific to the AZERTY keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62195253/2641825).

Answer (score 0):

On an AZERTY keyboard press:

- ctrl shift 8 to go to List item
- ctrl shift 7 to go from

The same in excel as

ctrl [
ctrl ]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

On a QWERTZ mac keyboard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> worked for me. And jumping back worked as expected with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.