# Vim and azerty keyboards

Tags: vim, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, azerty-keyboard

I recently started learning Vim and before I go deeper I have a question I need answered.

Using a AZERTY keyboard, should I remap the keys for the commands and shortcuts to fit the position of the keys of a QWERTY keyboard?

I am asking this because obviously quite a lot of thinking must have being put creating thoses commands, and when I see how far the '$' is on a AZERTY keyboard compared to the QWERTY one for example I can't help but think it might feel wrong at some point.

Here is the AZERTY layout: http://www.nathael.org/Data/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.svg

I don't even know if it will be possible to remap the way I would need, basically only remapping for command input, so I need so opinions from the 'pros' and/or azerty users.

Comment: I've been using Vim for 5 years with an AZERTY keyboard and didn't encounter a single issue.

Comment: @romainl you did not remap anything is that right? Everything is a matter of getting used to in the end then?

Comment: just to chime in, i've switched to dvorak about 3 years ago, and haven't looked back. I never changed any of the mappings either. In the end, it's all about muscle memory, so i wouldn't fret too much about remapping stuff if there's no really good reason for it

Comment: I also use vim with azerty, but I changed my keyboard layout a bit to make it more developer friendly: https://github.com/r03/azerty

Answer (score 4):

I also use an azerty keyboard, and I didn't remap the keys in order to fit the qwerty keyboard.

But I take profit of the very easy accessibility of some unused chars, like `é`, `è`, `à`, `ç` (all the accentuated characters) and have some maps like this:

```
noremap à @
noremap ç @@
noremap § \
```

(The last one is so useful that I remapped it outside of Vim, on my linux system-wide keyboard configuration)

But I think that remapping all keys to fit the qwerty keyboard is more a source of confusion, than a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

My current remapping for AZERTY in `~/.vimrc`:

```
" 1. Move to the end of the line
noremap m $
" 2. Search backward for the word under the cursor
noremap µ #
" 3. Navigate to the help tag under the cursor
noremap ' <C-]>
```

Further explanations:

1. I don't use marks, so decided to remap `m` in normal mode. This is practical since the `m` key is just after the movement keys  `hjkl` on the AZERTY keyboard.
2. `µ` is on the same key as `*` which searches forward for the word under the cursor. This is a logical choice, similar to `n` and `N` for forward and backward searches.
3. The key `'` is actually the result of pressing `CTRL-ù` in the terminal. This key is next to `m` on the keyboard. Its use for tag navigation was inspired by two questions here [how do i type CTRL ] on a QUERTZ keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932702/how-do-i-type-ctrl-on-a-qwertz-keyboard-in-order-to-jump-to-a-tag-with-vim) and on vi.stackexchange [tag navigation using CTRL ] does not work](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5732/tag-navigation-using-ctrl-does-not-work-with-non-english-keyboard-on-windows).

In addition, I mapped caps lock to escape at a system level ([how to do it in debian](https://martin.hoppenheit.info/blog/2014/mapping-caps-lock-to-escape-in-debian/)). I'm not a really experienced vim user so these mappings are likely to change.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any plugins, or reference for what you ask but I can share what I personally use.

With this you can use the top row symbols of your keyboards to use the numbers without shift ! Very useful and decreases the risk of RSI.

I think the only "useful" key you lose is ' (to go to the line of a bookmark) but I think ` is more useful (remapped to ù) because it goes not just to the line of the bookmark but also the specific character of that line that is bookmarked

```
  map à 0
  map & 1
  map é 2
  map " 3
  map ' 4
  map ( 5
  map - 6
  map è 7
  map _ 8
  map ç 9

  nmap ù `
```